# Prove $\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)g(x)}dx=\lambda f(c)\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)}dx+(1-\lambda)g(c)\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)\in C[a,b],f(x)>0$,Prove that:
$\exists! \xi\in(a,b)$
$$\int_{a}^{\xi}{f(t)}dt=\int_{\xi}^{b}{\frac{1}{f(t)}}dt$$

Is this a form of the mean value theorem for integrals？And I want to get introduction to the theorem.The more detailed the better, introducing as many forms as possible

**My question**

> **Prove** Let $f$ and $g$ be two nonnegative continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. There exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
>   $$\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)g(x)}dx=\lambda f(c)\int_{a}^{b}{g(x)}dx+(1-\lambda)g(c)\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx$$

I think this is a form of mean theorem.But I can't prove it.And this is related to above question.In addition,I think that the condition could $f$ and $g$ satisfy the intermediate value theorem.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I would like to inform you that while StackExchange is a Q/A site, [more than just a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/) is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

Comment: @RobertZ Could you please cancel closed?I have edited question.

Comment: It's useless to add @RobertZ because he's *not* the only one who closed your question, so he's [*not* pingable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/259305).

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 So what should  I do?Can't I cancel the closed?

Comment: You may [edit] your question to provide your own attempts to solve your problem, like [my recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112770/upper-bound-on-expected-norm-of-subgaussian-random-matrix).  Since this question has been [edit]ed, it should enter the Reopen review queue.  You need five re-open votes to reopen this question.  From the timeline of this question, we can see that few users voted to [reopen](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1155024) your question.

Comment: Where is the Reopen review queue?Emm..,I don't know how to vote?

Comment: 1. Click on "[reopen]" to find the queue.  2. No, you *can't*.  You need more reputation to cast close/reopen votes on your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Let us define $$F\left(x\right):=\int_{a}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt-\int_{x}^{b}\frac{1}{f\left(t\right)}dt.$$ Clearly, $F$ is continuous and, since $f>0$, we see that $$F\left(a\right)<0,\,F\left(b\right)>0$$ and, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there exists some $\xi\in\left(a,b\right)$ such that $$F\left(\xi\right)=0.$$ Furthermore, $F$ is derivable and from [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) we can see that $$F^{\prime}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}>0$$ hence $F$ is increasing, that is, $\xi$ is unique.

Comment: Thanks. The question belongs to a form of mean theorem? @Marco Cantarini .

Comment: @梦里年华似烟花 It is a consequence of the intermediate value theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus.